# Python Scipy v1.1.0 Kendall tau-b p-value calculation

Tags: python, scipy, p-value

The Kendall tau-b p-value calculation in Scipy version 1.1.0. says:

```
pvalue : float
The two-sided p-value for a hypothesis test whose null hypothesis is an absence of association, tau = 0.
```

However, it does not explicitly say which test is being used.

Does anyone know where to find that information?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/stats/stats.py#L3974-L4169).

For the automatic method they use the normal approximation that you find on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient#Significance_tests). The exact method is a bit more contrived and is described at the beginning of chapter five of [1].

[1] Maurice G. Kendall, "Rank Correlation Methods" (4th Edition), Charles Griffin & Co., 1970